# Can Visual Studio 2017's "Implement Interface" command generate C# 5 code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, in the "*Quick Actions and Refactorings*" menu, when I click "*Implement Interface*", I get implementations that use newer features of C#, like this:

```
public int ConnectionTimeout => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

The problem is that my company is using C# 5 and so we can't use this newer syntax.  I know older versions of Visual Studio would generate this code instead:

```
public int ConnectionTimeout { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
```

Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2017 to do this?  I've set my project to compile using C# 5.

Edit: I noticed that the code generator is inconsistent.  If the interface has a bool member that only has a getter, it uses the old syntax.  Otherwise it uses the new syntax.  This makes me think that I'm out of luck.

```
private interface myint
{
    bool bool1 { get; }
    bool bool2 { get; set; }
    bool bool3 { set; }

    int int1 { get; }
    int int2 { get; set; }
    int int3 { set; }

    string string1 { get; }
    string string2 { get; set; }
    string string3 { set; }
}

private class myclass : myint //I clicked "Implement Interface" on this
{
    public bool bool1
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool bool2 { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool bool3 { set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public int int1 => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public int int2 { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public int int3 { set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public string string1 => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string string2 { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string string3 { set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Comment: on the project properties, under the advanced tab, does changing the default language c# 5 alter the autogened code?

Comment: @Kyle, no it doesn't.  I forgot to add that in my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Code Style -> General*, scroll to *Code block preferences* section and change the preference *For properties*, *For indexers* and *For accessors* from *"Prefer expression block"* (default) to *"Prefer block body"*.

[image]